# Django model with a list

Tags: python, django

How to implement a list in a Django model?

Lets say I have a `UserProfile` model, and each user can have a list of mortgages (undefined quantity) defined by `MortgageModel`.

```
class MortgageModel(models.Model):
   bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   sum = models.BigIntegerField()

class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   # list of morgtages?
```

my only idea is to make a old school list, where every mortgage can point to another one or null, like this:

```
class MortgageModel(models.Model):
   bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   sum = models.BigIntegerField()
   next_mortgage = MortgageModel(null=True, default=null)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   mortgages = MortgageModel(null=True, default=null)
```

is there any other possibility?

Comment: Why not just use a `ForeignKey` relationship between `UserProfile` and `MortgageModel`?

Comment: list is simple to iterate and delete

Comment: In order to make a ForeignKey relation I would have to use filters to iterate over mortgages. Wouldn't it be faster to use a list?

Comment: A Django model is a Python representation of a database record. A model's fields (e.g. CharField) can only include data types that can be saved in database columns (e.g. character, integer, etc.) A Python list is not a data type that is represented in most common databases (ignoring the idea of a list serialised to XML/JSON/etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to assign a `ForeignKey` to `User` , so that each `Mortgate` 'belongs' to a user. 
That is how a ***One-To-Many relationship*** is done. Then, if you want to get the list of Mortgages a user have, you'd filter them out like `MortgageModel.objects.filter(related_user=user)`

So, you'd have something like

#### Model

```
   class MortgageModel(models.Model):
       bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
       sum = models.BigIntegerField()
       related_user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

    class UserProfile(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#### View

```
list_of_mortages = MortgageModel.objects.filter(related_user=user)
```

Comment: how to iterate mortgages?

Comment: @user2449761 You can query them out using filters.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer!

Comment: Wouldn't "oldschool" list be faster than filters?

Comment: @user2449761 oldschool list means wrong database modeling ;) Take a look at database normalization (good place to start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)